# Ubuntu can not wake up from sleep when I enabled UEFI fast boot

Tags: uefi, suspend

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 AMD64 with Core i3-2100 and GA-H61M-DS2,Ubuntu can not wake up from sleep when I enabled UEFI fast boot,Ubuntu can wake up from sleep when I disabled UEFI fast boot,is there any solution?

Comment: May be a bug. If you didn't yet, try a later kernel, e.g. `linux-generic-lts-xenial` *(which is 4.4, [relatively old too](https://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxVersions), but whatever)* — will it help or not, good to have anyway. Also, [enable Magic SysRq](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/admin-guide/sysrq.html), check that shortcuts working, then get the freeze, and try "Alt+SysRq+r" to take keyboard from Xorg *(in case it's Xorg hangs)*, then "Ctrl+Alt+F1" to swich to a terminal, and… for starters just tell if it's working.

Comment: Also, if you're dual-booting with Windows *(which I assume you do)*, you really don't want fastboot enabled, because hibernation *(which is what fastboot actually is)* [in Windows is badly implemented](https://sudopacman.wordpress.com/2015/01/09/dont-use-ntfsfix-in-linux-just-turn-off-fast-boot-in-windows/), and you may get your data on NTFS drive screwed.

Comment: UEFI fast boot like GRUB hidden disabled USB enter my UEFI and my GRUB,it also disabled this person samsung laptop motherboard Samsung https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2224618 .I can program my AMI UEFI with press Power Button for a few seconds or remove CR2032,but I can not SPI my AMI UEFI.By the way I do not use Windows since it is not free.

Comment: Sorry, I've a problem reading your comment. Are you saying that when fast boot disabled, USB is not working? The person you linked has problems with non-working shortcut for entering BIOS/UEFI setup. Thus their boot have been bypassed to GRUB. If it's your problem, have you tried entering `fwsetup` in GRUB prompt, [as the 4-th comment suggested](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2224618&p=13026513#post13026513)?